# Trying to remove white space without my home slider disappearing

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, removing-whitespace

my problem is that i experience white spaces on my mobile version between slider images on the following website: [athleteperks.co.uk](https://athleteperks.co.uk)

I've been told to you use the following code:

}

.swift-slider-outer {
    height: auto !important;

}

this code removes the white spaces between my sliders on my homepage, however it removes my header slider on the mobile and desktop versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CSS you need to remove the following line:

```
.swift-slider-outer {height: 600px!important;}
```

it is within your `@media (max-width: 768px)` media query. This is forcing your slider to be a certain pixel width and is overriding your solution which is `.swift-slider-outer { height: auto !important;}`

FYI - `!important` is got great practice. It's always best to try to see what exactly is going wrong first.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it worked. Really appreciate it!